# Bash: How to determine if a command exists without running it?

Tags: bash, macos

I'm using Bash on OS X. There are several commands that I want to determine if exist, but don't want to run them in case they do exist and have unwanted effects. For example, if I wanted to test if `destroyPC` were a command, but didn't want to test it by running it. Is there a simple way to do this, like `isCommand destroyPC`?

**EDIT**: This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script). I was looking for "does this COMMAND exist" without thinking to look for "does this PROGRAM exist". Remember that commands are just programs.

Comment: Check if `destroyPC` is in any of your `$PATH`. Or you should try `which destroyPC`.

Comment: @PanwenWang Thanks, this does work, but the answer from the question Ostone0 linked is quicker.

Comment: @Ostone0 Thanks, that does answer it. I updated the original question to redirect people to it.

Comment: Please mark the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `command -v <your-command>`. It will return error code 1 if the command isn't found and 0 if it is, so you can use it like this:

```
if ! command -v foo &> /dev/null
    #command does not exist
else
    #command exists
fi
```

Here, I'm using the `&> /dev/null` to silence the output.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question
Lets say we want to test the existence of 'ls' commands, this is what I would type on the command line

`command -v ls`

If the commands doesnt exist, there will be no output
If it does(assuming bash), the output will be /bin/ls